# Antlr Syntax error: mismatched input 'p' expecting WS

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar myProject;

program: WS EOF myRules;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
myRules: myRule+;
myRule: SELECTOR OPEN declarations CLOSE;
declarations: declaration+;
declaration: PROPERTY EQ value ENDSYMBOL;
value: INT | STRING | COLOR;

SELECTOR : (('#'CHAR+)|('.'CHAR+)|CHAR+);
PROPERTY : [A-z-]+;

STRING : '"' .*? '"';
INT : [0-9]+ ;
COLOR : '#' [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F];
CHAR: [A-z];

EQ : ':' ;
OPEN : '{';
CLOSE : '}';
ENDSYMBOL : ';' ;
```

Now my input is this:

```
p {
    color: #054593;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Now, when i parse this i get the following error:

*Syntax error: mismatched input 'p' expecting WS*

I have red many questions here on stack and googled a lot already, but I simpeley can't find a anwser. What am I doing wrong in my grammar?
Why does the program needs a WS and how do I fix this.
Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the program needs a WS: Because that's what you specified, the declaration for `program` means: first a WS, then an EOF, and then myRules.

Comment: @Jesper is right: your program rule doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So what you saw is: If i don't put in ws anywhere but just state it as a rule; it will still do its work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first thing you do in your grammar is demand WS:

```
program: WS EOF myRules;
```

So, lacking any whitespace characters, your parse fails.  I'd simply suggest:

```
program: myRule*;
```

since you're discarding whitespace already with the skip option.